# Insert data into 2 different tables from a single form using OctoberCMS Builder Plugin

Tags: database, forms, model, builder, octobercms

I am using OctoberCMS builder plugin to create forms to store data into database. By default, each model belongs to a single database table. And a form can store the data into a single database table. So how to Insert data into 2 different tables captured from a single form using Builder Plugin.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that You'll have to handle the saving process manually using the model class.

1- Open your model class.

2- Write a model even function like `public function afterSave(){}`

For example if I have a `total` field in `reservation` model and I wanna this field value to be inserted automatically in another table called `accounting`.

```
public function afterSave(){
    $accounting = \Namespace\Pluginname\Models\Accounting::find(1);
    $accounting->myField = $this->total;
    $accounting->save();
}
```

So within `afterSave`, `beforeSave`, `beforeCreate` or `afterCreate` you can handle the saving process of the models.

To see the differences between those functions you can read more on this link: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events

Comment: Good answer. Though in this generic scenario I'd perhaps suggest a different way of saving the other data, i.e. instead of ```find(1)``` (which just finds the model with `id=1`, and otherwise fails, or doesn't it?) one could do ```findOrCreate(['reservation' => $this->id])``` to save in a row associated with this specific ```reservation```, just to maybe give a more "realistic" example, and point to the [Laravel / Elouent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) for some deeper digging, ...

Comment: ... and also to [relations](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations) and the [relation behaviour](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#configuring-relation) which may be even more appropriate to use in this scenario.
Just smartassing around here, though :P, and trying to give some additional pointers to other newbiews like me, which might be good for further reading.

Comment: Good example. Of course `find(1)` was a non realistic example of the code he can write to access any model in the application :D

Comment: I had wanted to add here for a while already (and hope I won't get banned here for spamming - so am doing it stealthily in an old answer's comment where no one else will notice :P) that you should please support the [proposal for an OctoberCMS stackexchange section](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms/). We need more people who have a reputation of 200 or more who committed to the proposal, in order for it to go into beta. So your support would make a difference. :)